# Optimizing this enormous for loop

Tags: c#, for-loop, unity-game-engine, optimization

So I have this for loop:

```
for (int i = 0; i < meshes.Count; i++)
        {
            for (int j = 0; j < meshes.Count; j++)
            {
                for (int m = 0; m < meshes[i].vertices.Length; m++)
                {
                    for (int n = 0; n < meshes[i].vertices.Length; n++)
                    {
                        if ((meshes[i].vertices[m].x == meshes[j].vertices[n].x) && (meshes[i].vertices[m].z == meshes[j].vertices[n].z))
                        {
                            if (meshes[i].vertices[m] != meshes[j].vertices[n])
                            {
                                meshes[i].vertices[m].y = meshes[j].vertices[n].y;
                            }
                        }
                    }
                }
            }
        }
```

Which goes through a few million vectors and compares them to all other vectors, to then modify some of their y values. I think it works, however after hitting play it takes an unbelievably long time to load (currently been waiting for 15 minutes, and still going). Is there a way to make it more efficient? Thanks for the help!

Comment: Not that this will make your processing any faster, but given your `if` conditions, your fourth loop probably should be `for (int n = 0; n < meshes[j].vertices.Length; n++)`

Comment: @derpirscher Thanks, the reason I didn't bother putting the right variable there is that all vertices arrays are the same size, so (as far as I know) it shouldn't matter.

Comment: Could you, please, describe the *initial* problem? You have several million vectors and you want to get (perform) what?

Comment: @DmitryBychenko Yeah sorry, so basically I created a bunch of meshes using Perlin noise, and put them next to each other. This for loop is for making it so that the vertices on the edges of the meshes are at the same y level as the ones from the meshes next to them.

Comment: Your inner if seems needlessly expensive. You’re saying "if the x's are the same and the z's are the same _and the whole vertex is different_, which will presumably compare x and z again (I’m assuming these are structs). You could just compare y's there, but if there are no side effects you could probably just skip the compare and assign y anyway.

Comment: @sellotape Oh yeah that's very true, thanks!

Comment: Instead of trying to optimize this loop, I would try to generate your meshes so that each vertex's y-coordinate is the same as its neighbors.  If you know the overall length and width of your terrain, then you should be able to calculate the index in `meshes` of a given mesh's neighbors.  Using a loop like this -- even if you optimize it -- the vast majority of your comparisons are between meshes that are not neighbors, and so that's all wasted time.

Comment: How expensive is getting meshes[i]? You could capture that in a local variable immediately within the i-loop, instead of recalculating that every time

Comment: @HansKeﬆing OP should likely do that as well as cache the various Count/Length values as well as meshes[j] and the various vertices array accesses. Anything that can be stored in a local within the outer loop body... Seems silly but I've seen caching such values drastically speed up similar workflows

Comment: @pinkfloydx33 Yes, I meant that as an example. Of course also cache/precalculate all other values. Even if one array lookup or length lookup takes "just a little bit" of time, times "a few million" it adds up.

Answer (score 2):

As I read this, what you're basically doing, is that for all vertices with the same `x` and `z`, you set their `y` value to the same.

A more optimized way would be to use the Linq method `GroupBy` which internally uses hash mapping to avoid exponential time complexity like your current approach:

```
var vGroups = meshes.SelectMany(mesh => mesh.vertices)
    .GroupBy(vertex => new { vertex.x, vertex.z });
foreach (var vGroup in vGroups)
{
    vGroup.Aggregate((prev, curr) =>
        {
            // If prev is null (i.e. first iteration of the "loop")
            // don't change the 'y' value
            curr.Y = prev?.y ?? curr.y;
            return curr;
        });
}

// All vertices should now be updated in the 'meshes'
```

Note, that the final `y` value of the vertices depends on the order of the meshes and vertices in your original list. The first vertex in each `vGroup` is the deciding vertex. I believe it'll be opposite of your approach, where it's the last vertex that's the deciding one, but it doesn't sound like that's important for you.

Furthermore, be aware that in this (and your) approach you are possibly merging two vertices in the same mesh if two vertices have the same `x` and `z` values. I don't know if that's intended but I wanted to point it out.

A additional performance optimization would be to parallelize this. Just start out with call to `AsParallel`:

```
var vGroups = meshes.AsParallel()
    .SelectMany(mesh => mesh.vertices)
    .GroupBy(vertex => new { vertex.x, vertex.z });
// ...
```

Be aware, that parallelization is not always speeding things up if the computation you are trying to parallelize is not that computationally expensive. The overhead from parallelizing it may outweigh the benefits. I'm not sure if the `GroupBy` operation is heavy enough for it to be beneficial but you'll have to test that out for yourself. Try without it first.

For a simplified example, see [this fiddle](https://dotnetfiddle.net/g2bu87).

Comment: I'm trying to use what you showed, however I get the error "Operator '?' cannot be applied to operand of type 'Vector3'. I don't really know how this kind of syntax works, so I can't figure out how to fix it. Any idea?

Comment: @TheWalrus ah, that just means `prev` is not nullable in your case, so you can just replace `curr.Y = prev?.y ?? curr.y;` with `curr.Y = prev.y;`. Basically `prev?.y ?? curr.y` means: "give me `prev.y` if `prev` **is not** null, otherwise use `curr.y`". Check the [null-conditional operator](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/csharp/language-reference/operators/member-access-operators#null-conditional-operators--and-)

Answer (score 2):

You are comparing twice unnecessarily.

Here a short example of what I mean:

Let's say we have meshes `A`, `B`, `C`.

You are comparing

- `A`, `A`
- `A`, `B`
- `A`, `C`
- `B`, `A`
- `B`, `B`
- `B`, `C`
- `C`, `A`
- `C`, `B`
- `C`, `C`

while this checks e.g. the combination `A` and `B` two times.

---

One first easy improvement would be to use e.g.

```
for (int i = 0; i < meshes.Count; i++)
{
    // only check the current and following meshes
    for (int j = i; j < meshes.Count; j++)
    {
        ...
```

do you even want to compare a mesh with itself? Otherwise you can actually even use `j = i + 1` so only compare the current mesh to the next and following meshes.

---

Then for the vertices it depends. If you actually also want to check the mesh with itself at least you want `int n = m + 1` in the case that `i == j`.

It makes no sense to check a vertex with itself since the condition will always be true.

---

A next point is **minimize accesses**

You are accessing e.g.

```
meshes[i].vertices
```

**five times!**

rather get and store it once like e.g.

```
// To minimize GC it sometimes makes sense to reuse variables outside of a loop
Mesh meshA;
Mesh meshB;
Vector3[] vertsA;
Vector3[] vertsB;
Vector3 vA;
Vector3 vB;
for (int i = 0; i < meshes.Count; i++)
{
    meshA = meshes[i];
    vertsA = meshA.vertices;

    for (int j = i; j < meshes.Count; j++)
    {
       meshB = meshes[j];
       vertsB = meshB.vertices;

       for(int m = 0; m < vertsA.Length; m++)
       {
           vA = vertsA[m];

           ...
```

---

Also note that a line like

```
meshes[i].vertices[m].y = meshes[j].vertices[n].y;
```

Actually shouldn't even compile!

The vertices are `Vector3` which is a `struct` so assigning the

```
meshes[i].vertices[m].y
```

only changes the value of a returned `Vector3` instance but shouldn't in any way change the content of the array.

You would rather work with the `vA` as mentioned before and at the end assign it back via

```
vertsA[m] = vA;
```

and then at the end of the loop assign the entire array back **once** via

```
meshA.vertices = vertsA;
```

---

And well finally: I would put this into a `Thread` or use Unity's [JobSystem](https://docs.unity3d.com/Manual/JobSystem.html) and the burst compiler and meanwhile e.g. display a progress bar or some User feedback instead of freezing the entire application.

---

Yet another point is floating point precision

you are directly comparing two `float` values using `==`. Due to the floating point precision this might fail even if it shouldn't e.g.

```
10f * 0.1f == 1f
```

is not necessarily true. It might be `0.99999999` or `1.0000000001`.

Therefore Unity uses only a precision of `0.00001` for `Vector3 == Vector3`.

You should either do the same and use

```
if(Mathf.Abs(vA.x - vB.x) <= 0.00001f)`
```

or use

```
if(Mathf.Approximately(vA.x, vB.x))
```

which equals

```
if(Mathf.Abs(vA.x - vB.x) <= Mathf.Epsilon)`
```

where `Epsilon` is the smallest value two floats can differ

Comment: Wow, I didn't realize the code could be optimized this well, thanks a lot!

Answer (score 2):

You want to make `Y` equal for all vertices with the same `X` and `Z`. Lets do just that

```
var yForXZDict = new Dictionary<(int, int), int>();
foreach (var mesh in meshes)
{
    foreach (var vertex in mesh.vertices)
    {
        var xz = (vertex.x, vertex.z);
        if (yForXZDict.TryGetValue(xz, out var y))
        {
            vertex.y = y;
        }
        else
        {
            yForXZDict[xz] = vertex.y;
        }
    }
}
```

You should replace `int` to the exact type you use for coordinates

Comment: Wow that's such a simple and clean solution, thanks so much!